# Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'timer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a stopwatch using React. I hit the start button and the stopwatch starts, but when I hit the stop button I receive a `TyperError`

```js
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {secondsElapsed: 0};
        this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this);
        
    }

    getSeconds() {
        return ('0' + this.state.secondsElapsed % 60).slice(-2);
    }

    getMinutes() {
        return Math.floor(this.state.secondsElapsed / 60);
    }

    getHours() {
        return Math.floor((this.state.secondsElapsed / 60) / 60);
    }


    handleStartClick() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({
                secondsElapsed: (this.state.secondsElapsed + 1)
            });
        }, 1000)
    }

    handleStopClick() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.getHours()}:{this.getMinutes()}:{this.getSeconds()}</h1>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleStartClick}> start </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleStopClick}> stop </button>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Home;
```

The stopwatch will continue to run even after the error. I was wondering if it was unable to read `this.timer` because it was created in a function, `handleStartClick`.

Comment: Why dont you bind handleStopClick in constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to bind `this` to `handleStopClick`. By not doing so `this` isn't the `this` of the component.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {secondsElapsed: 0};
    this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this);
    this.handleStopClick = this.handleStopClick.bind(this);
}
```

It is easy to avoid this by using arrow functions, they bind `this` of the parent for you.

```
handleStartClick = () => {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
            secondsElapsed: (this.state.secondsElapsed + 1)
        });
    }, 1000)
}

handleStopClick = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already correctly bound `handleStartClick` in the constructor:

```
this.handleStartClick = this.handleStartClick.bind(this);
```

You need to do the same with `handleStopClick`:

```
this.handleStopClick = this.handleStopClick.bind(this);
```

The reason is the same in both cases - to make sure that any reference to `this` inside either function still refers to the component instance. Otherwise, when called as an event handler, the "context is lost", and `this` becomes `undefined` - as you're seeing.